# Display related data from table in Laravel Blade one to one relationship

Tags: laravel

the error says attempt to read name on null. when I tried

```
  <td>{{ $respondent->household_heads->name }}</td>
```

In my respondent table, I have a foreign key household_id which contains the household_head the respondent belongs to.

Here is my  **household_heads**  schema:

```
Schema::create('household_heads', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**respondents** schema:

```
Schema::create('respondents', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('household_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('household_id')->references('id')->on('household_heads');
        });
```

**HouseholdHead**  model:

```
class HouseholdHead extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function respondent(){
        return $this->hasOne(Respondent::class);
    }


}
```

**Respondent** model

```
class Respondent extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function household_heads(){
        return $this->belongsTo(HouseholdHead::class);
    }
}
```

**household_head** table:

[image]

**respondent** table:

[image]

**controller**:

```
    public function index()
{
     
    $respondents = Respondent::with('household_heads')->get();
    return view('map', compact('respondents'));


    

}
```

**table.blade.php** :

```
@foreach ($respondents as $respondent)
         <tr>
            <td> {{$respondent->name}} </td>
                              
            <td>{{ $respondent->household_heads->name   }}</td>

          </tr>
@endforeach
```

I want to display on the table.blade.php the household_head name in the table.blade.php in which my respondent belongs to

Answer (score 3):

You have to define the foreign key .. because Laravel couldn't resolve the foreign key, Laravel assume your foreign key name is `house_hold_id`

More info about [One To One Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

```php
class HouseholdHead extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function respondent(){
        return $this->hasOne(Respondent::class, 'household_id', 'id');
    }


}
```

```php
class Respondent extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function household_heads(){
        return $this->belongsTo(HouseholdHead::class, 'household_id');
    }
}
```